# How do I create a Url object from the public file URI?

Tags: 8, files, uri

How can a `Url` object be created from a file URI? Using the URI for a public file as a parameter for `Url::fromUri()` gives this error.

> UnexpectedValueException: External URLs do not have internal route parameters. in Drupal\Core\Url->getRouteParameters().

```
$file = File::load($file_id);
$file_uri = $file->getFileUri();
$menu_link['url'] = Url::fromUri($file_uri);
```

Here is the class and method in question:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x

Note that I don't need to get the actual URL in string format, I need to generate a Url object from the Url class that points to a file. This is because I am attempting to modify the path of a menu link and unfortunately that is not a simple matter of providing a URL string in Drupal 8.

This is the code I am using.

```
function teeprop_preprocess_menu__main(&$vars) {
  foreach($vars['items'] as $key => $menu_link) {
    if (!empty($menu_link['url']->getRouteParameters())) {
      $node_id = $menu_link['url']->getRouteParameters()['node'];
      $node_entity = Node::load($node_id);
      $node_type = $node_entity->getType();

      if ($node_type == 'pdf') {
        $file_id = $node_entity->get('field_pdf_file')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
        $file = File::load($file_id);
//         $file_url = $file->url();
        $file_uri = $file->getFileUri();
        $vars['items'][$key]['url'] = Url::fromUri($file_uri, ['absolute' => TRUE]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for menu link URLs, but I think that external URLs are supported. This could be done by doing `$menu_link['url'] = Url::fromUri($file_uri, ['absolute' => TRUE]);`. I'm not confident in this, but I use this in freelinking module to send file URIs to Link render element's #uri property.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately that causes the same error. I can't believe how difficult this is.

Comment: file_create_url($file->getFileUri() should create an absolute path which should then work with fromUri().

Comment: That also fails with the same error. I wonder why is the Url being interpreted as external?

Comment: Can you POST file URI here..

Comment: Can you post the full code around you're altering / changing the menu link? I think that might help clarify.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the original question to include the full code.

$file_uri is `public://pdfs/Dashboard Saved Search.pdf`
$file_url is `http://tee-prop.dev/sites/default/files/pdfs/Dashboard%20Saved%20Search.pdf`

Comment: Wow. I didn't really even need to generate a Url object to accomplish my needs. Just assigning the URL string was enough to generate the link properly:

`$vars['items'][$key]['url'] = $file_url;`

I then added a class to the menu item `li` element instead of the `a` element because `$vars['items'][$key]['url']` is no longer an object and there is no way to add attributes. This is not ideal and doesn't answer the question I asked, but it is a way around it that works for my situation:

`$vars['items'][$key]['attributes']->addClass('menu-item--file-link');`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the following should do what you need:

```
Url::fromUri(
  File::load(1)->url()
);
```

(I've tested this in a local 8.4.2 installation, and it yields a Url object that can be rendered without an error.)

The functions are admittedly named very misleadingly. Even though `::fromUri()` *sounds* like it should accept the return value of `::getFileUri()`, namely `public://...`, it actually only accepts `internal:`, `base:`, `entity:` and "external" URLs.

So you need to use `->url()` to get the external URL of the file, and then pass that to `::fromUri()`.

Comment: Be careful if you use ->isExternal(), it will consider your internal file as external file.

Comment: @ChristopheCARON yes, this is another example of the terminology being ambiguous/misleading. "External" seemingly refers to all URLs that aren't either Drupal routes or Drupal system files - the public filesystem is considered "external".

Comment: $file->url() was deprecated in D9 and removed from D10.  See other answers for a working option.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$url = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generate($file_uri);
$form['elements']['my_link'] = Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl('Your_link_title', $url)->toRenderable();
```

You can also use other methods from `Drupal\Core\File` like `generateAbsoluteString`,

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 10

```php
$file = File::load($file_id);
$vars['items'][$key]['url'] = $file->createFileUrl();
```

That will give you the relative URL as a string.  Something like `"/sites/default/files/my_file.pdf"`.  If you want an absolute URL for some reason you can use `$file->createFileUrl(FALSE)`.